# How can I express my motivation to join a Masters program if I have no experience in the area?

Tags: application, statement-of-purpose, application-cover-letter, motivation

I am planning to apply to a specific master program in Finance. I do not have any experience in Finance and have never worked in any project related to Finance. But I am very interested to study it because I want to enlarge my research area (which is in signal processing) and have more job opportunities in the future. I really believe that I can excel in the program if I study it.

Can you please help me in writing two or three sentences that can motivate my interest to a program although that I have no work experience on it? I am trying to write a cover letter and I need your help.

Comment: Finance at the higher levels is fairly mathematical (stochastic differential equations, stochastic calculus). There's a lot of probability theory. Have you taken courses on random processes? If so, try to draw a connection between what you know and the topics covered in the masters program.

Comment: You just expressed your motivation to us. You want to enlarge your research area and improve your employability. Why not say that?

Comment: @ErikM Thank you for your comment:)

Comment: @Flyto You are right. I will also say that in my letter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the new area isn't just a random choice. Think about what it was about that area that drew you to it and say some things about that. It would also be good to work in a bit about how your background and training makes this a natural trajectory for you. If you have read papers in the new area and find them interesting and think you can contribute to the ideas there, say something about that.

Even your statement here that you want to broaden your horizons is positive, but, alone, it is worth only a little.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question. I just specified the program that I am interested in!

Comment: Exactly, I think I really should read some papers related to the program and see why I am interested.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you believe that you can excel? Find a good reason or two for that and put these in the letter.

Did you research the topic? You say you have no experience and never worked on it, so do you even know what it is about, or do you only know public believes (that might be really wrong)? If you didn't research it, then do. If you did and still believe you want to do it, then show in your letter that you actually know what you are getting into and explain why you want it.

You want to enlarge your research area, that is good. How would this program help? What will you be able to do, with both knowledge from signal processing and this program? If the both are totally disjoined and have no overlap, then think again why you want it. If there is something that you could do better when knowing both topics, in the letter it goes.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your words. I have edited my question. I just specified the program that I am interested in! Yes you are right. I think should first research well the program and then see what is interesting for me.